# How to compare 2 folders and if a file is missing take actions?

Tags: php, image

I'm using a script for resize photos to another folder and keep the same name  automaticaly found [here](http://networking.mydesigntool.com/viewtopic.php?tid=543&id=31) and working great!

I have hundreds of photos in my source folder and i'm going to do this action often. I would like to optimize the time by making it resize the photos only if it sees the photos doesn't exist in the destination folder. How can we do that?

**Here is the full code used:**

```
function imageResize($file, $path, $height, $width)
{

       $target = 'smallphotos/';

       $handle = opendir($path);

       if($file != "." && $file != ".." && !is_dir($path.$file))
       {

              $thumb = $path.$file;

              $imageDetails = getimagesize($thumb);

              $originalWidth = $imageDetails[0];

              $originalHeight = $imageDetails[1];

              if($originalWidth > $originalHeight)
              {

                     $thumbHeight = $height;

                     $thumbWidth = ($originalWidth/($originalHeight/$thumbHeight));

              }
              else
              {

                     $thumbWidth = $width;

                     $thumbHeight = ($originalHeight/($originalWidth/$thumbWidth));

              }

              $originalImage = ImageCreateFromJPEG($thumb);

              $thumbImage = ImageCreateTrueColor($thumbWidth, $thumbHeight);

              ImageCopyResized($thumbImage, $originalImage, 0, 0, 0, 0, $thumbWidth, 
              $thumbHeight, $originalWidth, $originalHeight);

              $filename = $file;

              imagejpeg($thumbImage, $target.$filename, 100); 

       }

       closedir($handle);

}

    $source = "photos";

    $directory = opendir($source); 

    //Scan through the folder one file at a time

    while(($file = readdir($directory)) != false) 
    { 

           echo "<br>".$file;

           //Run each file through the image resize function

           imageResize($file, $source.'/', 640, 480);

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you could just add one more condition to the resize function

```
if ($file != "." && $file != ".." && !is_dir($path.$file) && !is_file($target.$file) {...
```

This should keep it from trying to do anything if the target file already exists.

Another option would be to check if the destination file exists before calling the function

```
while (($file = readdir($directory)) != false) { 
    echo "<br>".$file;
    //Run each file through the image resize function (if it has not already been resized)
    if (!is_file("smallphotos/$file")) {
        imageResize($file, $source.'/', 640, 480);
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting code but sadly it keeps resizing all the files even if it does exist in the target folder. Shouldn't we add something too in the ***while*** loop ?

Comment: @BackTrack57 That's strange, it worked ok for me when I tested it. Sure, you could do the same check in the while loop. That should make it a little faster, too since you would avoid making an unnecessary function call. I updated the answer to show one way you could do that.